# Yii2, render ActiveForms from another model inside a ListView

Tags: listview, yii2, active-form

I'm struggling to modify some data that I'm passing to a `listView` with an `ActiveDataProvider`.

This a part of my `_form.php`

The model here represents a Product.

**_form.php**

```
use common\models\Product


<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin();?>


<?php echo
    ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => new yii\data\ActiveDataProvider
        ([
            'query' => common\models\productsAdditionalInfo::find()->where(['code' => $productsArray]),
            'pagination' => false,
        ]),
        'itemView' => '_list-grammature',
    ]);

?>
<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

In my `_list-grammature.php` I'm basically rendering the data from `productsAdditionalInfo` which is also a container that took data from other tables.

**_list-grammature.php**

```
<?php

    $additionalInfoForm = ActiveForm::begin(
        [
            'id' => "form-grammatura-{$idFormAndButton}",
            'method' => 'post',
            'action' => ['backend\controllers\productsAdditionalInfoController/updateProductsAdditionalInfo'],
        ]
    );
?>

    <th colspan="4">Factory</th>
</tr>
<?php
    echo $this->render(
        'items/_factory-list',
        [
            'form' => $form,
            'forCode' => $model->code,
            'factories' => $model->factories,
        ]
    );
?>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">Raw Materials</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        echo $this->render(
            'items/_raw-materials-list',
            [
                'form' => $form, 'forCode' => $model->code,
                'rawMaterials' => $model->rawMaterials,
            ]
        );

        echo Html::submitButton(
            '<i class="fas fa-cloud-upload"></i> Save',
            [
                'id' => "btn-save-{$model->firm_id}",
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary has-icon-left px-4 mx-2 elevation-5',
            ]
        )
    ?>
<?php $additionalInfoForm->end();?>
```

I've only took a small part of the page to give a hint of her behavior.

Basically the render part work like I expected, but when I try to modify the various textArea/input and submit the changes, the page is still bindend to the `Products` model and not to my `ProductsAdditionalInfo` model.

The queryString accordingly to what I'm saying is:

`http:/.../backend/PRODUCTS/update?id=10`

I don't know if I'm doing a lecit operation, I'm basically inserting in a ActiveForm, a listView which create several ActiveForms from another model, but when I try to submit one of the inner ActiveForms it updates (with no data) the model of the outer ActiveForm.

What In my mind I was thinking to get:

```
<form Product>

    <form1 productsAdditionalInfo>
        <button1 submit data to productAddionalInfo>
    </form1 productsAdditionalInfo>

     <form2 productsAdditionalInfo>
        <button2 submit data to productAddionalInfo>
    </form2 productsAdditionalInfo>

<Button submit Product>
</form Product>
```

What instead I get:

```
<form Product>

    <div data-key=Product1>
        <button1>
    </div data-key=Product1>

     <div data-key=Product2>
        <button2>
    </div data-key=Product2>

<Button submit Product>
</form Product>
```

Comment: dude you are nesting forms which is not allowed anyhow, the **Content Model** of the `form` element is defined as **Flow content, but with no form element descendants.** you cant do that , you are wrapping the `ListView` into a `ActiveForm` and then start another form inside the `_list-grammature`, you need to revise your logic

Comment: above all what are your requirements? isnt there any open source extension/widget that can do the job for you? or get rid of the outer most `ActiveForm`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes my intention was to nesting form element, an outer form which configures a PRODUCT and some inner forms with the products specifications from other relations.

By clicking the submit button of the inner form I can update every single specifications, by clicking the outer form submit button I can update a Product.

Before you're replies I deleted the outer activeForm, and now I can update every single inner form, but In this way I think I lost the possibility to update a single product.

I don't know if there is an extension that can help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585832/yii-2-nested-forms

I found something similar to what I'm aiming.